# Can a POE switch connect to port on Cisco C3524-XL switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, power-over-ethernet

I have an installation that utilizes Cisco Catalyst C3524-XL switches to connect different buildings to a site network. I need to connect POE cameras to this network. I would like to utilize a Trendnet POE switch such as TPE-S44 to feed the cameras. Can I connect my cameras to the TPE-S44, connect the TPE-S44 to any open and configured port on the C3524-XL and have my camera footage viewable on the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is how a lot of companies do it.